# Github action determine if previous commit's test passed and only run tests if files changed?

Tags: github-actions

I have a github action that uses `actions/checkout@v3` in tandem with `tj-actions/changed-files@v37` to determine files changed in a PR, so that I know which tests need to run.

For tests that don't need to run, I automatically "pass" the action with a green checkmark because each test is required.

**Problem is: `tj-actions/changed-files@v37` looks at all files for the entire PR have changed, rather than the changed files since the last successful run. Can I determine what files have changed based on the last successful test and run tests based on that instead?**

Is there a way to get a list of changed files based on the diff since the last time the actions passed, and only trigger needed actions off of those changed files?

Here's an example of the github actions yaml file:

```
name: "Example tests"
on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
            - dev
    pull_request:
        types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]
        branches-ignore: [releases]

jobs:
    changed-files:
        name: Determine changed files
        runs-on: [self-hosted, external]
        outputs:
            cpp: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.cpp_any_modified }}
        steps:
            - name: Checkout project
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
              with:
                  fetch-depth: 0
                  submodules: recursive
                  token: ${{ secrets.GITHUBTOKEN }}
            - name: Check which files have changed
              id: changed-files
              uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v37
              with:
                  files_yaml: |
                      cpp:
                        - cpp/**
    cpp_test:
        needs: changed-files
        uses: My-Companys-Name/github_workflows/.github/workflows/test.yml@main
        with:
            branch_name: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
            test_file: cpp/test_suite.yml
            skip: ${{ needs.changed-files.outputs.cpp == 'false' }}
```

And here is an example of test.yml (reusable workflow):

```
name: "Trigger Tests to External Machine"
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      branch_name:
        required: true
        type: string
      test_file:
        required: true
        type: string
      skip:
        required: false
        type : boolean
        default: false

run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is running the ${{ inputs.test_file }} test

jobs:
  testing:
    name: Tests
    runs-on: [self-hosted, external]
    steps:
      - name: Dispatch test to external machine
        if: ${{ !inputs.skip }}
        run: | 
          # Send the test file to the external machine using http requests
      - name: Display test results
        if: ${{ !inputs.skip }}
        run: |
          # Display test results from the external machine
      - name: Notify supervisor of test cancellation
      - name: Download test result
        if: ${{ always() && !inputs.skip }}
        run: |
         # Download test results for artifact use
      - name: Upload test results
        if: ${{ always() && !inputs.skip }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test-results
          path: ${{ env.test_folder }}
          retention-days: 14
      - name: Notify skipped
        if:  ${{ inputs.skip }}
        run: echo 'Test ${{ inputs.test_file }} requested to be skipped'
```

Comment: It's a bit tricky here. Most [diff actions on the Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?category=&type=actions&verification=&query=diff) are just checking for the current PR, and don't compare the current commit with specific ones. In your case you would need to compare the current commit with the last commit which ran the same workflow successfully. It's very specific and will need customization (from an existing action, or through the creation of a new step by step in your workflow).

Comment: I'm thinking this github action might help: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-set-shas?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: You're right, this one with some customizable steps will help :)